# Determine correct answers from multiple questions

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have multiple radio lists and multiple check box lists containing questions where some can select multiple answers and some single depending on the control.

I can't use a database for this task.

The controls would be placed on an asp.net form.

I can provide the HTML for the controls if required but I don't think that would really help for the question I have.

Depending on the selected answers/options would decide what result would be displayed from the 2 results available.

I know I can do an if clause which checks every control and if the answers fit the criteria I can show result one else result two but is there a cleaner approach I could use? I feel this way seems heavy maintenance if the criteria changes in future?

Edit 1: example

```
What is 1 + 1

A. 2
B. 3

Select all tech companies
A. Microsoft
B. Google
C. McDonald's
```

So option A from question 1 and options A and B from question 2 would result in a success message anything else would not.

Comment: Is there some kind of structure/logic about how the answers are distributed depending on the answers, or is it completely arbitrary?

Comment: If you start with a known state, you can use the CheckedChanged event for each control to modify the state, so when you're ready to display the results, you don't have to query all the controls because the state object has already been updated. But the question is sort of confusing tbh.

Comment: I personally think, keeping everything in static html will definitely increase your maintenance headache if you were to add more questions or to modify questions those are obsolete. You will also have script nightmare if you were to deal with answers somehow. Not sure why you can't use a back-end. But using a back end will reduce your overall headache.

Comment: I could use JSON or XML file? I've amended my question with an example to help what I'm trying to achieve. If I just JSON/XML I'm not sure how to determine the correct answers?

Comment: That is not how you approach this problem. 1. Write code with multiple `if ..else` statements and make it work 2. When you can see whole implementation picture you can refactor it with more maintainable implementation. Ah! And would be great and efficient if you don't forget to do step 0. Write tests before writing code ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several layers required in your application.

1. Repo layer - Something to hold your data which could be XML or JSON.  My opinion is that JSON is easier.
2. Service Layer - To generate a collection of questions, present the first question, determine if correct, and next steps
3. View Layer - Receive the question and render the proper input controls on the form.

Sample JSON:

```
Questions: [Question:{
        Id: 1,
        QuestionText: "What is 1+1?",
        AnswerType: "Single"
        ProvidedAnswers: ["1","2","3","4"],
        CorrectAnswers: ["2"],
        CorrectMoveToQuestion: 2,
        IncorrectMoveToQuestion: 1
    }, Question:{
        Id: 2,
        QuestionText: "Select all tech companies",
        AnswerType: "Multiple"
        ProvidedAnswers : ["Microsoft","Google","McDonald's"],
        CorrectAnswers: ["Microsoft","Google"],
        CorrectMoveToQuestion: 3,
        IncorrectMoveToQuestion: 2
    }
]
```

Sample C#

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string QuestionText {get;set;}
    public string AnswerType {get;set;}
    public string[] ProvidedAnswers {get;set;}
    public string[] UserAnswers {get;set;}
    public string[] CorrectAnswers      {get;set;}
    public int  CorrectMoveToQuestion    {get;set;}
    public int  IncorrectMoveToQuestion  {get;set;}
}

public class QuestionService {

    public bool ValidateAnswers(string[] correctAnswers, string[] userAnswers)
    {
        //PseudoCode - I'm not doing your work for you.
        foreach(var uA in userAnswers)
        {
            //Check that correct Answers match and that the user has not selected any wrong answers
        }
        return true; // false; depending on result      
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good. I'll give it a try soon but I know how to serialise and deserialise JSON but how do I check if all the correct answers have been selected from each control?